# Vue.js computed property : [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am very new to Vue.js, so please be patient with me if the problem is too simple.

so I have the following code of `Home.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div>
      <b-table striped hover :items="borrowingHistroy"></b-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import userData from '@/data/user_data';

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data() {
    return {
      userId: 0,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    borrowingHistroy: () => userData[this.userId].borrowingHistory,
  },
};
</script>
```

The code did not get rendered as I get the following error/warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined"
```

if I change the `borrowingHistry` in the `computed` to the following then it works:

```
 borrowingHistroy: () => userData[0].borrowingHistory,
```

so that warning must mean `this` is not defined here?

But then how can I use the `userId` defined in "data"?

****** modified ******

The following are my other parts of code:

`main.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';

import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

`App.vue`:

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/images/HPL.png">
  <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
  </div>
  <router-view />
</div>
</template>
```

`router/index.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

`store/index.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could simplify the computed property definition using parenthesis, so you will keep the **application's context:**

```
 borrowingHistroy() {
   return userData[this.userId].borrowingHistory
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the component instance as arrow function parameter :

```
  borrowingHistroy: (vm) => userData[vm.userId].borrowingHistory,
```

According to [the official docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#computed) :

> Note that if you use an arrow function with a computed property, this won’t be the component’s instance, but you can still access the instance as the function’s first argument:

```
computed: {
  aDouble: vm => vm.a * 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks @BoussadjraBrahim, but do you know how to pass the vm from main.js to a specific page?

Comment: `vm` refers to `this` and it's available in every child component but in some contexts isn't accessible

Comment: Thanks, I have added my other parts of code, and it is indeed because of the arrow function problem you have pointed out, if I use the conventional function as @NikolayZubkov's solution then it works.